# PHP variable as input for img src attribute

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make gallery which displays all the .jpg files in some local directory, but it makes me problem.

```
   <?php

   $directory = "img/";   
   $images = glob($directory."*.jpg");
   foreach($images as $image)
   {
       echo '<img src="file://'.$image.'" /><br />'
   }
   ?>
```

Somehow path to jpg file is not correctly passed to the src attribute, where I am wrong?

Comment: Assuming you get a broken image icon, what does right clicking say is the path that it's trying? What does "View source" on the browser show? Do modern browsers even allow file:// anymore? And you might want to have file://img/ as the path or whatever the full, absolute path is.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the **file://** on the src.

from

```
echo '<img src="file://'.$image.'" /><br />';
```

to

```
echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/><br />';
```